# Plug Textbox to Taskbar (or Titlebar window) with C#

Tags: c#

I'm coding a application using C# to embed textbox to Taskbar as below picture:

(Taskbar)
https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B-E8VK5m5ETqZTI2ZjBlODUtOGI0MC00ZDRhLThjNzItMmE2MTA5NjZlODE5&hl=en

(Title)
*https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B-E8VK5m5ETqZWE0NzM2MjktZTc5NS00MjdmLThkMmUtMTZjODA3MWUyZTRm&hl=en*

--
I downloaded Window API code pack and view some example but I still don't know how to perform my scenario.

Anyone help me for a solution or article (I searched Google but didn't find any article).

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Updated link: 

http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/uN3U1Of2VwwxyOSU4LevDw?feat=directlink

Answer (score 0):

A simple Google search revealed the following links (there are more):

1: http://www.buttonsandbars.com/OnlineHelp/ICreate.Controls.Bars~ICreate.Controls.Bars.TaskBar.html

2:
http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/taskbar-controls-t3330966.html

3:
http://www.buttonsandbars.com/OnlineHelp/ICreate.Controls.Bars~ICreate.Controls.Bars.TaskBarItem.html

The first URL demonstrates with full source, how to draw a hyperlink on the taskbar with an image from what I can see, so this may be worth investigating into further.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Please refer, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378460(v=vs.85).aspx

Refer a sample.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2219/Extending-Explorer-with-Band-Objects-using-NET-and